# Redis отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python, django, redis, redis-server

Пытаюсь подружить Redis и Django 2.0.3. Раньше не использовал Redis. Установил его на Windows 10. Кроме того установил Redis Watcher. Подключаю к Python 3.6 32-bit. Использую модуль redis.
Попробовал сделать следующее:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
```

Получил:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 484, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 541, in _connect
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 529, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 667, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 484, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 541, in _connect
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 529, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    r.set('foo', 'bar')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1171, in set
    return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 673, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
```

Пробовал запустить Redis Server через "Службы", но он сразу выключился, потому что ни одна программа к нему не обратилась. Как запустить сервер Redis и подключиться из Python?

Comment: А `redis` server нормально работает и слушает на порту `6379`?

Comment: [связанный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows/20200022#20200022)

Comment: @MaxU, вопрос решен тем, что предложено по вашей ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Решение найдено. Изложу здесь по-русски как установить и протестировать Redis на Windows.
Установка:

1. Скачайте и распакуйте [бинарник Redis из бранча 2.6](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/raw/2.6/bin/release/redisbin64.zip)
2. Скопируйте все извлеченные файлы в `c:\redis\bin`
3. Создайте еще одну папку `c:\redis\inst1`
4. Скачайте и распакуйте [бинарник RedisWatcher из бранча 2.4](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/raw/2.4/msvs/bin/release/rediswatcherbin.zip)
5. Запустите InstallWatcher.msi. Он создаст Windows service с названием
   Redis watcher.
6. Откройте консоль локальных серверов Windows Services console и
   запустите Redis watcher service.
7. (опционально) RedisWatcher должен быть установлен C:\Program Files
   (x86)\RedisWatcher. Там находится конфигурационный файл
   watcher.conf, который надо отредактировать, чтобы добавить
   дополнительные инстансы, используя различные пути, описанные в шагах
   2 и 3. Перезагрузка не нужна.

Как протестировать:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
True
>>> r.get('foo')
b'bar'
```